# XWalkView initialize view asnyc in Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, xwalkview

I'm using XwalkView as WebView in my Android App. It's nested in a fragment and every time when I open the fragment it needs 2-3 Seconds until the fragment is displayed. Before that the app freezes. So I would like to show a loading indicator while the XwalkView is rendered and make the fragment changes immediately.

Anyone knows how to realize that?

Comment: I could improve it by using ViewStub and replace the view when the fragment becomes visible. Not sure if it is the best solution, it still is not fluent but much better than before.